# Xamarin MvvmCross: Cannot Resolve v4.FragmentManager

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library, mvvmcross

In my Xamarin Android, I want to resolve v4.fragment manager so, I'm resolving it in the following way

```
var ss = Mvx.Resolve<Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager>();
```

But, I'm getting error:

```
MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve type Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager
  at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type t) [0x0001c] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\IoC\MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs:199 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve[T] () [0x00000] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\IoC\MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs:189 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.Resolve[TService] () [0x00005] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Mvx.cs:34 
  at TJX.Core.IoC.MvxDependencyResolver.ResolveType[T] () [0x00001] in /Users/ali00261/Loyalty-MultiBanner-Mobile/TJX.Core/IoC/MvxDependencyResolver.cs:11
```

Can anyone advice what am I doing wrong and how to resolve it ?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I want to replace a FrameLayout in my `MvxFragment<TViewModel>` with a support.v4.fragment.
`ZXingScannerFragment` is a support.v4.Fragment provided by 'ZXing' to scan barcode.

```
var scanFragment = new ZXingScannerFragment();
var ss = Mvx.Resolve<Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager>();
ss.BeginTransaction()
                    .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_scancontainer, scanFragment)
                    .Commit();
```

My aim is to replace a view(frame layout) with a support.v4.Fragment

Comment: I do not believe MvvmCross registers a `FragmentManager` against the IoC container as you can have multiple `FragmentManager's` in a single app. What are you trying to do that you want to resolve `FragmentManager` for?

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r I updated my question. I want to replace a view(Layout) in my MvxFragment with a support.v4.fragment

Comment: If you are dealing with children fragments inside of your fragment you can use `ChildFragmentManager` to achieve nested fragments. It will be a property from the base `Fragment` implementation `MvxFragment` inherits from.

Comment: for replacing a fragment, `ChildFragmentManager` expects an `App.Fragment` but I want to replace with a `Support.v4.App.Fragment`. How can I replace it with a `Support.V4.App.Fragment` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ChildFragmentManager`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Fragment.ChildFragmentManager/) to support managing Fragments inside of Fragments.

```
ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
   .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_scancontainer, scanFragment)
   .Commit();
```

In terms of `App.Fragment` vs `Support.V4.App.Fragment`, it looks like you are using the wrong dependencies.

Mvvmcross offer two `MvxFragment` class type to match those offered in Android:

- **Native Fragment** - which can be found in [MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging/) and offers `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.Fragments.MvxFragment`. This class matches to the native Android `Fragment` introduced in [API 11](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).
- **Support Library Fragmet** - which can be found in [MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4 nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4/) and offers `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxFragment`. This class matches to the [Android Support Library Fragmets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html).

You need to use the *Support Library Fragment* version of `MvxFragment` in order to use `Support.V4.App.Fragment` with a `ChildFragmentManager`.

Comment: directly using the code `ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction..//` gives me error that scanFragment cannot be passed as parameter as of `support.v4.app.fragment type`. I cannot change scan fragment type as I'm getting it from a third party nuGet(ZXing). Where do you want me to use Support Library Fragment version of `MvxFragment` ?

Comment: Would you mind including the error message you are getting in you question? Looking at [ZXing Fragment](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android/ZXingScannerFragment.cs) source it is a Support Fragment, so I think the issue is that your MvxFragment is not from `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4` package

Comment: I got it.. I updated my fragment class to inherit `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxFragment` as you asked to for and its working now. Thank you.